# Only show times with minutes that are divisible by 5

Tags: c#

I am trying to show time only in with minutes divisible by 5 (ie: 1:00, 2:05, 3:45.. etc..)

Though when I output the time, I get 10:00, 10:01, 10:02, 10:03 and 10:04. Never 10:05. and the minutes are always between 0 and 4.

The hours and minutes are separate Int's

What am I doing wrong?

```
     public string TimeAsText {
         get {
              return Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + (Minutes % 5).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
         }
     }
```

Comment: Where are you filtering out the minutes not divisible by 5?

Comment: there is no condition... `if (Minutes % 5 != 0) return string.empty;`

Comment: The _Modulus_ operator (`%`, also known as _mod_) is the remainder from integer division.  If you take `n % 5` for n in { 1 ... 11 }, you will get `{1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1 }`.  You want integer division, not modulus.  If you want some rounding, add 2 or 3 to the value before you divide by 5.

Comment: @Flydog57 said exactly what I was about to. You are asking the program to display `Minutes % 5`, which will never be a multiple of 5

Comment: I feel so dumb. That was in my face the whole time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `(Minutes % 5)` only returns 0,1,2,3,4.
If you want to get 5, you

```
public string TimeAsText {
     get {
          return Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + ((Minutes / 5)*5).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
     }
 }
```

Or if you want to round,

```
   public string TimeAsText {
         get {
              return Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + ((int)(Math.Round(Minutes / 5.0)*5)).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
         }
     }
```

Comment: Also look at the options for the format parameter in `int.ToString(string format)`. You can express a two-digit, 0-padded format directly.

Comment: I still don't see how this answers the question of only wanting to show hours with minutes divisible by 5 and 5 only.

Comment: or `return $"{Hours:00}:{((int)(Math.Round(Minutes / 5.0)*5)):00}";`

Comment: @MarkC: My understanding is that if he wants to display something at `1:02`, he will display `1:00` or `1:05`.  The question isn't quite clear about this

Comment: @Flydog57 I interpreted the entire question as the headline: `Only show times with minutes that are divisible by 5`

Comment: @MarkC.: Exactly, but this part (_"Though when I output the time, I get 10:00, 10:01, 10:02, 10:03 and 10:04. Never 10:05"_) is where I got my idea from

Comment: @Flydog57 that's because OP is not filtering the times correctly and is just returning the `{hours}:{minutes % 5}` instead of figuring out if the `minutes % 5 == 0` before doing any property-setting

Comment: I went the round route.

Comment: @user-44651: consider using Olivier Jacot-Descombes' solution for formatting.  I find `$"{Hours:00}:{((int)(Math.Round(Minutes / 5.0)*5)):00}";` **a lot** more obvious than the `Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')` formatting you are using

Answer (score 3):

the modulo operator ('%') returns the remainder of the division.  you don't want the remainder.  you want to use the remainder to determine your output.

// the untested long version

```
if(Minutes % 5 == 0) // IE. minutes is evenly divisible by 5
{
   return Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
}
```

// the untested shorter version

```
return Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + (Minutes % 5 == 0) ? Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') : "00";
```